# Property Injection with Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac, owin

I want to use Autofac for property injection. Here's my setup:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

        builder.RegisterType<TeamManagerContext>().PropertiesAutowired();

        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacMvc();

        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

BaseController:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Application DB context
    /// </summary>
    public TeamManagerContext TeamManagerContext { get; set; }
}
```

TeamManagerContext is always null (never injected). I've spent quite some time looking online without any further indication of what might be wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to goole for it or search here on SO?

Comment: Yes I have. Everyone seems to be doing the exact same thing as I am.

Comment: Try in an empty project to make sure it works or it doesn't. Maybe when you simplify it works and doesn't in your real, more complex scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have auto wired properties within the TeamManagerContext itself but haven't told the controller registrations that they have properties autowired, have you tried:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly).PropertiesAutowired();
```